# Camera detection in windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8

I am developing an app in windows 8 that requires camera to capture picture. So what I need to do to know whether camera is present(Suppose assume that desktop doesn't have webcam, while windows 8 tablet has a camera), so I only need to show controls to show camera when camera is present on the device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use this API:
JS:

```
Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.findAllAsync(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceClass.videoCapture).done(yourHandler);
```

C#:

```
var interfaces = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector, null); 
foreach(DeviceInformation devInfo in interfaces) { /* stuff */ }
```

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformation.aspx) has more information on the other aspects of this API

Since you are using c#, [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Device-Enumeration-Sample-a6e45169/sourcecode?fileId=44728&pathId=410862369) sample will be more specific.

Comment: The second link seems broken, sample is available [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Device-Enumeration-Sample-a6e45169).